# Visual Studio stuck initializing with strange icon in status bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I build my project, Visual Studio 2015 takes forever, with the status bar looking like this:

[image]

The icon is animated: the arrow moves down, while the little boxes fall into the open square. If I had to guess, this would mean VS is trying to download something (packages?) but gets stuck somewhere. What does this icon mean, exactly? What does *Initializing* mean?

This is a Visual C++ project that built fine in Visual Studio 2013, but I'm moving to VS2015 because I needed `noexcept`. It uses SFML, but I've already replaced the library files with the *Visual C++ 14 (2015) - 64-bit* version.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Initializing" means but the icon is the "building" icon. Does it hang permanently forcing you to kill the process, or does VS come back to life after a while?

Comment: I should've clarified -- VS doesn't actually hang, the build just takes forever, and I can cancel it whenever.

Comment: It's not look like stuck in build. If it's stuck at the time of build you can't close the VS at that time. When build start you can't close the VS at that time before it's complete the project fully.

Answer (score 2):

Question is to old but maybe my answer will be useful for someone in 2023. To make work correctly the `animated icon` On `Visual Studio 2022` you need to disable the option shown on the screen (if you disable second one also the animated icon will disappear at all):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found and terminated a lingering Visual Studio 2013 process that still had the solution open -- this solved the problem. (In retrospect, I should have just rebooted!)

Comment: Not really , reboot is not a solution to all windows issues ,

Comment: Always always turn fusion log on and enable detail logging to output window it gives way more info

Comment: @loneshark99
In 2023 the same problem. Does anyone know how to disable this animated icon? can't find lingering process to terminate it