# Animated icon at bottom right of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have no idea what this icon is in the status bar at the bottom of visual studio.  Everything else in the status bar has a tooltip except this one icon.  It will sometimes be there and sometimes it isn't.  Usually when it shows up, it stays.  I feel like something is happening, but I can't see anything.  I can leave visual studio sitting there for an hour and its still going.

Anyone shed some light on this?

[image]

Comment: After looking at it for a while I feel like it might be sprinkling fairy dust on my code to make it better.  I can say this for sure, it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the project is building. Sometimes the icon stays for longer time, in which case VS probably executes some project analysis.

See also [Visual Studio 2017 Icon with down arrow in status bar - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43947218/217666)