# Visual Studio 2022 - How to disable animated icon on the status bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

`Visual Studio 2022` has an animated icon on the status bar:

[image]

Sometimes it is animated when I doing nothing (no coding, no compiling) and it's very annoying.

Please tell me what does it indicates and how can I turn the animation off?

Comment: Do you have live unit testing enabled or background code analysis enabled?

Comment: do not know, mebe some extentions do it

Comment: Are you sure it's not activated by the auto-backup feature? Why is it a problem if it animates when it's "not doing anything"? If it is animating, surely the IDE has some internal workings. There are also some guidelines in apps that when a game is paused, for example, the leafs or some sort of animation happens on the HUD or menu just to tell the player that the PC or console didn't freeze/lock-up. Consider this a similar approach for an IDE (as IDEs can also lock-up even if the chance is very low). For short: it's by design and if it animates, then it does something and it lets you know.

Comment: @TheNomad you've answerd my first question. Thanks!
may be you can answer my second question: how can I turn the animation off? (let's IDE do the job in background, without animation)

Comment: As I said, if it's by design (and it is), then you prolly can't. Maybe use the Feedback feature to ask for it to become optional, but I don't think they will do it since it's good practice for it to be animated when it "does something".

Comment: @TheNomad definitely it is a bug. I just launch the Visual Studio, doing nothing 2 hours and this icon is animating. only restart helps

Comment: @TheNomad
seems the problem is old. so this is not a feature, this is a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446780/visual-studio-stuck-initializing-with-strange-icon-in-status-bar

Comment: For me, this always occurs when I click the Hot Reload button while no .cs files are modified. I some time edit the xaml file and then hit the hot reload button. THis causses the animation to always stay on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make work correctly the `animated icon` you need to disable the option shown on the screen (if you disable second one also the `animated icon` will disappear at all):

[image]

Comment: seems like a bug in Visual Studio